# Generating Javascript from coffeescript equivalent to manual javascript in _.each underscore

Tags: coffeescript, underscore.js

I have a code in Javascript as :

```
 _.each(this.collection.models, function (student) {
            $(this.el).append(new StudCloneItemView({ model: student }).el);
        }, this);
```

While I am writing This in coffescript as

```
_.each this.collection.models  , (student) => 
$(@el).append new Item ({ model:student }).el
```

which generates

```
_.each(this.collection.models, function(student) {
      return $(_this.el).append(new Item({
        model: student
      }.el));
    });
```

Which isn't desirable as per my requirement . The last segment of "this" element has been missing into the generated javascript . Its very important.

How would I generate The javascript as mentioned on top using the coffeescript I mentioned for _.each ????

Is there anyway to do that ?? Or am I missing any syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript:

```
_.each(this.collection.models, function (student) {
    $(this.el).append(new StudCloneItemView({ model: student }).el);
}, this);
```

and what your [`=>`](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow) CoffeeScript produces:

```
var _this = this; // This is somewhere above your _.each in the generated JS
_.each(this.collection.models, function(student) {
    return $(_this.el).append(new Item({
        model: student
    }.el));
});
```

are functionally equivalent. You don't need the context argument to [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) since the `=>` generates an alias for `this` (called `_this`) that is used inside the callback.

---

As an aside, Backbone collections have [various Underscore methods mixed in](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so you don't have to say `_.each(@collection.models, ...)`, you can use `each` directly on the collection:

```
@collection.each (student) =>
    @$el.append(new StudCloneItemView(model: student).el)
```

I've also switched to the pre-built [`$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) that your view already has, there's no need to build a new jQuery object on each iteration.

Comment: yes I realised tht after your post . That was really helpful how underscore and coffeescript are mixed

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
_.each @collection.models, ((student) ->
  $(@el).append new StudCloneItemView(model: student).el
), this
```